# ui-sref is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

ui-sref in my application is working partially. Mean for some link it is generating href but for other's not. below is my code:-

// for ng-repeat it is not working but for others it is working.

```
<nav class="site-links" ng-controller="itemsController">
<ul class="nav-links">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a ui-sref="{{item.link}}">
            <span>{{item.Description}}</span>
        </a>
    </li>  
    <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>                
</ul>
```

Could you take a look??

Comment: Can you show us your `item` object's structure?

Comment: did u find a solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the following routes defined in you router:

```
$stateProvider
       .state( 'testState', {

              url: '/test',
              templateUrl: 'app/templates/test.html',
              controller: 'testController'

       });
```

You can link to this state via the `ui-sref` directive ONLY by its name. So, the following is valid:

```
<a ui-sref="testState">Something</a>
<a href="/test">Something</a> <!-- Notice the difference. Here we're using the reference to the route. -->
```

So, for the `ui-sref` you need to tell it the **NAME** of the state and for the normal `href`, a simple route is fine.

Comment: I do the same but <a ui-sref="testState">Something</a> is not clickable